# Is possible to address the output SIMD register by using an input register

Tags: c++, c, sse, simd

Is it possible to use the scalar values of an input vector to index the output vector? I try to implement the following function in SIMD but I can not find any solution.

```
 void shuffle(unsigned char * a,    // input a
              unsigned char * r){   // output r
     for (i=0; i < 16; i++)
            r[i] = 0;
     for (i=0; i < 16; i++)
            r[a[i] % 16] = 1;
 }
```

An example input / output vector would look like this

```
unsigned char * a = {0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1, 0, 0 };
... do SIMD magic
//                   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15
unsigned char * r = {1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
```

I was not able to find any suitable instruction that can dynamicly address the left side of an assignment. Maybe this function can be implemented by shifting operations? Did anybody implement something similar?

Comment: No, you can't easily do this. The closest thing would be `_mm_shuffle_epi8`, which is a general purpose permute, but I don't see any obvious way to apply it here. You really want the inverse of this instruction, which doesn't exist.

Comment: In your example, shouldn't element r[0] also be 1 ?

Comment: Yes, I was thinking if I could use the _mm_shuffle_epi8 instruction. But I could not come up with a solution. I was affraid to hear this.  Thanks for the fast answer though. And yes, r[0] should be 1.

Comment: FWIW you can do it with a loop, which is no more efficient than the original scalar version, but if this is going to be mixed in with a bunch of other SIMD code then it might be worthwhile, in order to avoid scalar code in the middle of your SIMD instruction stream.

Comment: Do think about shifting the register 16 times and comparing with the index position?

Comment: Yes, something like that, although you might be able to "early out" once you have processed the last index, so it might be less than 16 iterations in the general case, depending on what your data typically looks like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that _mm_shuffle_epi8 is indeed the key to a solution. The idea is to set individual bits according to the values of the input vector a. 
These bits are distributed over (horizontal OR) the bytes of the 128 bits wide 
register.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <immintrin.h>
/*  gcc -O3 -Wall -mavx test4.c                                  */
/*  gcc -O3 -Wall -msse2 -mssse3 -msse4.1 test4.c                */

int print_char128(__m128i * x);

int print_char128(__m128i * x){
  unsigned char v_x[16];
  _mm_storeu_si128((__m128i *)v_x,*x);
  printf("%4u %4u %4u %4u | %4u %4u %4u %4u | %4u %4u %4u %4u | %4u %4u %4u %4u  \n",
  v_x[0],  v_x[1],  v_x[2],  v_x[3],  v_x[4],  v_x[5],  v_x[6],  v_x[7],
  v_x[8],  v_x[9],  v_x[10], v_x[11], v_x[12], v_x[13], v_x[14], v_x[15] );
  return 0;
}


int main()
{
unsigned char  a_v[] = {0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1, 0, 0 };
/*unsigned char  a_v[] = {13, 30, 0, 10, 0, 6, 0, 2, 0, 0, 7, 0, 3, 11, 0, 0 };*/
  __m128i t0, t1, t2, t3;
  __m128i a, r, msk0, msk1, msk0_1, zero, bin_ones, one_epi8;

  /* set some constants */
  unsigned char  msk0_v[] ={1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
  msk0=_mm_loadu_si128((__m128i *)msk0_v);
  msk1=_mm_shuffle_epi32(msk0,0b01001110);
  msk0_1=_mm_blend_epi16(msk0,msk1,0b11110000);
  zero=_mm_setzero_si128();
  bin_ones=_mm_cmpeq_epi32(zero,zero);
  one_epi8=_mm_sub_epi8(zero,bin_ones);

  /* load indices */
  a=_mm_loadu_si128((__m128i *)a_v);

  /* start of 'SIMD magic'                                            */
  /* index a_i sets the a_i -th bit within a byte of t0 if 0<=a_i<8  */
  /* or set (a_i-8)-th bit within a byte of t1 if 8<=a_i<16          */
  t0=_mm_shuffle_epi8(msk0,a);
  t1=_mm_shuffle_epi8(msk1,a);
  /* horizontal OR of the bytes in t0 and t1: */
  t2=_mm_blend_epi16(t0,t1,0b11110000);
  t3=_mm_alignr_epi8(t1,t0,8);
  t0=_mm_or_si128(t2,t3);
  t1=_mm_shuffle_epi32(t0,0b10110001);
  t0=_mm_or_si128(t0,t1);
  t1=_mm_slli_si128(t0,2);
  t0=_mm_or_si128(t0,t1);
  t1=_mm_slli_si128(t0,1);
  t0=_mm_or_si128(t0,t1);
  t0=_mm_shuffle_epi32(t0,0b11110101);  /* end of horizontal OR */
  /* filter out the relevant bits */
  t0=_mm_and_si128(t0,msk0_1);
  t0=_mm_cmpeq_epi8(t0,zero);
  r=_mm_andnot_si128(t0,one_epi8);      /* the result is in r */
  print_char128(&r);

  return 0;
}
```

This should work quite fast: Aside from the instructions for setting the constants and loading the data it is only 15 SSEx instructions. On today's processors these instructions all have a latency of only 1 cycle.
The (reciprocal) througput is even smaller: 1/2 or 1/3 cycle.
Intrinsic *_mm_blend_epi16* is SSE4.1, some others are SSSE3.

Comment: wow your solution looks great. Thank a lot for sharing it. I still try to understand all details.

Comment: You don't need zeros as an input to `_mm_cmpeq` to generate all-ones.  Any input is equal to itself.  The CPU even takes advantage of this, by generating a uop that doesn't depend on the previous value of the register, when both operands are the same.  (i.e. it's recognized as a dependency-breaking instruction.)

Comment: NVM, looks like you are using your `zero` reg in the algorithm.  Otherwise, you could get `one_epi8` from `_mm_sign_epi8(bin_ones, bin_ones)`.  I thought there was a plain vector negate instruction, but maybe not.