# How to use _mm_extract_epi8 function?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, vectorization, sse, simd

I am using `_mm_extract_epi8 (__m128i a, const int imm8)` function, which has `const int` parameter. When I compile this c++ code, getting the following error message:

> Error C2057 expected constant expression

```
__m128i a;

for (int i=0; i<16; i++)
{
    _mm_extract_epi8(a, i); // compilation error
}
```

How could I use this function in loop?

Comment: You can't, i is not a constant. Unless you unroll your loop and write `_mm_extract_epi8(a,0)`, `_mm_extract_epi8(a,1)`, etc.

Comment: Non-portably, you could use `a.m128i_u8[i]`. With other compilers, you could use a union of __m128i and char[16]. But it is not a good sign if you need to iterate on vector elements like this.

Comment: The portable way is to `memcpy` the contents to a `char[16]` array and access the elements. In `C` a `union` is fine as well. What do you actually want to do?

Comment: @chtz: not memcpy, `_mm_storeu_si128` :P  Or `alignas(16) char bytes[16]` so you can use `_mm_store_si128`.  If you want to loop over the bytes of a vector one at a time, store/reload is more efficient anyway than an unrolled 16x `pextrb`.

Comment: @PeterCordes I guess for `movdqu`/`_mm_storeu_si128` it does not really matter (https://godbolt.org/z/Cg8AuX) -- for aligned stores it makes sense of course. I never understood why `_mm_storeu_si128` takes the destination as `__m128i*` and not `char*` or `void*`, i.e., always requires casting.

Comment: @chtz: you don't want it to split across a cache-line boundary.  On modern CPUs that usually won't defeat store-forwarding, but it will still consume extra resources when actually committing to L1d.  Re: the definition: I'm not impressed with Intel's intrinsics either.  So many poor decisions of what to provide (e.g. no memory-source `pmovzx*` intrinsic, and compilers have a hard time optimizing away the movd or movq load to create a `__m128i`), and clunky naming.  Finally with AVX512, though, integer loads/stores take `void*`.

Comment: @PeterCordes Actually, even the `_mm_store_si128` intrinsic does not really make any sense. If I need to cast the pointer to `__m128i*` anyway, I might as well just assign something directly to it (unless I want my code to be more verbose): https://godbolt.org/z/kbXXPV. But I agree that the poor API design of (many) intrinsics is an independent issue.

Comment: @chtz: oh, yes, dereferencing a `__m128i*` is exactly equivalent to `_mm_load/store_si128`.  In GNU compilers, that's how the intrinsic is implemented.  (While loadu/storeu cast it to `__m128i_u` which has an `__aligned__ (1))` attribute.)  Instead of having to memorize this, the load/store intrinsics seem like a reasonable way to communicate alignment info to the compiler.  And to make your C source look like you're writing asm for a 3-operand load/store machine with `__m128i` variables as vector registers, even though that's *not* really the case.

Answer (score 6):

First of all, you wouldn't want to use it in a loop even if it was possible, and you wouldn't want to fully unroll a loop with 16x `pextrb`.  That instruction costs 2 uops on Intel and AMD CPUs, and will bottleneck on the shuffle port (and port 0 for vec->int data transfer).

The `_mm_extract_epi8` intrinsic requires a compile-time constant index because [the `pextrb r32/m8, xmm, imm8` instruction](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pextrb:pextrd:pextrq) is only available with the index as an immediate (embedded into the machine code of the instruction).

---

If you want to give up on SIMD and write a scalar loop over vector elements, **for this many elements you should store/reload**.  So you should write it that way in C++:

```
alignas(16) int8_t bytes[16];  // or uint8_t
_mm_store_si128((__m128i*)bytes, vec);
for(int i=0 ; i<16 ; i++) {
    foo(bytes[i]);
}
```

The cost of one store (and the store-forwarding latency) is amortized over 16 reloads which only cost 1 `movsx eax, byte ptr [rsp+16]` or whatever each.  (1 uop on Intel and Ryzen).  Or use `uint8_t` for `movzx` zero-extension to 32-bit in the reloads.  Modern CPUs can run 2 load uops per clock, and vector-store -> scalar reload store forwarding is efficient (~6 or 7 cycle latency).

---

**With 64-bit elements, `movq` + `pextrq` is almost certainly your best bet.  Store + reloads are comparable cost for the front-end and worse latency than extract.**

With 32-bit elements, it's closer to break even depending on your loop.  An unrolled ALU extract could be good if the loop body is small.  Or you might store/reload but do do the first element with `_mm_cvtsi128_si32` (`movd`) for low latency on the first element so the CPU can be working on that while the store-forwarding latency for the high elements happens.

With 16-bit or 8-bit elements, it's almost certainly better to store/reload if you need to loop over all 8 or 16 elements.

If your loop makes a non-inline function call for each element, the Windows x64 calling convention has some call-preserved XMM registers, but x86-64 System V doesn't.  So if your XMM reg would need to be spilled/reloaded around a function call, it's *much* better to just do scalar loads since the compiler will have it in memory anyway.  (Hopefully it can optimize away the 2nd copy of it, or you could declare a union.)

See 
[print a __m128i variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13257166/print-a-m128i-variable/46752535#46752535) for working store + scalar loops for all element sizes.

---

**If you actually want a horizontal sum, or min or max, you can do it with shuffles in O(log n) steps, rather than n scalar loop iterations.**  [Fastest way to do horizontal float vector sum on x86](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996764/fastest-way-to-do-horizontal-float-vector-sum-on-x86) (also mentions 32-bit integer).

And for  summing byte elements, SSE2 has a special case of `_mm_sad_epu8(vec, _mm_setzero_si128())`.  [Sum reduction of unsigned bytes without overflow, using SSE2 on Intel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10932550/sum-reduction-of-unsigned-bytes-without-overflow-using-sse2-on-intel).

You can also use that to do signed bytes by range-shifting to unsigned and then subtracting `16*0x80` from the sum.  https://github.com/pcordes/vectorclass/commit/630ca802bb1abefd096907f8457d090c28c8327b

Answer (score 1):

Intrinsic `_mm_extract_epi8()` cannot be used with variable indices, 
as already pointed out in the comments. 
You can use the solution below instead, 
but I would use this solution only in a non-performance critical loop, 
such as, for example, printing results to file or screen.

Actually, in practice it is almost never necessary to loop over the 
byte elements of an `xmm`. For example, the following operations on `epi8` do not need
a loop over the elements (the examples may contain some self promotion):

- Horizontal minimum, maximum, sum, sum of absolute values, root mean square, avarage, bitand, bitor.
- [Prefix sum](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19494114).
- Computing the most frequentlty occurring element [(the modus)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45475938).
- [Variabele bit shift.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51789685)
- Create a [mask based on byte values.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29955471).
- Computing the [indices of the nonzero elements](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35681201).
- Etc. ect.

In these cases efficient vectorized solutions are possible.

If you cannot avoid a loop over the elements in a performance critical loop:
Peter Cordes' [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54496300/2439725) should 
be faster than the one below, 
at least if you have to extract many (2 or more) elements.

---

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <immintrin.h>
/* gcc -m64 -O3 -march=nehalem extr_byte.c */

uint8_t mm_extract_epi8_var_indx(__m128i vec, int i )
{   
    __m128i indx = _mm_cvtsi32_si128(i);
    __m128i val  = _mm_shuffle_epi8(vec, indx);
            return (uint8_t)_mm_cvtsi128_si32(val);
}  

int main()
{
    int i;
    __m128i x = _mm_set_epi8(36,35,34,33,  32,31,30,  29,28,27,26,  25,24,23,22,21);
    uint8_t t; 

    for (i = 0; i < 16; i++){
        printf("x_%i = ", i);
        t = mm_extract_epi8_var_indx(x, i);
        printf("%i \n", t);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
$ ./a.out
x_0 = 21 
x_1 = 22 
x_2 = 23 
x_3 = 24 
x_4 = 25 
x_5 = 26 
x_6 = 27 
x_7 = 28 
x_8 = 29 
x_9 = 30 
x_10 = 31 
x_11 = 32 
x_12 = 33 
x_13 = 34 
x_14 = 35 
x_15 = 36
```

Comment: If we had dword variable-shuffles in SSE2, we could have used that (and a right shift to handle the byte-within-word part of the index), but we don't get `vpermd` until AVX2.  But then sure for variable access to a byte in a YMM or ZMM maybe.  I think this is better than `vpcompressd zmm0{k1}, zmm1` with `k1 = 1<<idx` , because on most CPUs `vpermd` is faster than compress.